# Flow, multi select checkbox and email action

Tags: email, formula, visual-workflow, email2case, checkbox

Good morning

Since I have no coding background, visual flow is a must for me (At least for now) and for some time now I try to understand the tool, its functions and limitations and what better approach than solve requirements (fictional for now since I am not working as an admin).

My requirement was the following:
1. Web-to-Case -------> New Case lands in SF 
2. Case record has a custom picklist field that is populated with a value that the Record Submitter chose.
3. User needs an automation that according to the value of the custom picklist field will allow him/her to email (I am aware that there is a limitation in flow to up to 5 emails) certain contacts in SF that have the same value stored in a custom text field in the contact record.

First Flow approach.

1. Custom Button - provides caseId (for flow testing an assignment element is used)
2. User Screen1 - Drop Down list to prompt user to choose a value based on the picklist field values present on the case object (i am trying to automate this step).
3. User Screen2 - Dynamic record choice Multi Select Checkboxes with Choise Label and Choise stored value and NO additional options populated (if populated only one value would be stored).
4. Assignment to store the contact emails in a variable - {!varTContactEmails} equals {!Contacts}, where {!Contacts} are the Screen multi Select fields.
5. Assignment to remove brackets - {!varTContactEmail} equal {!fvarTRemoveBrackets}, where {!fvarTRemoveBrackets} equals to

`TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({!varTContactEmail},"[", ""),"]", "")) + ";"`

6. Assignment add left value to Collection - {!CollectionVariableContactsEmail} add {!fvarTGrabLeftValue}, where {!fvarTGrabLeftValue} equals to

`(LEFT({!varTContactEmail},FIND(";",{!varTContactEmail})-1))`

7. Assignment remove last parsed value - {!varTContactEmail} equals {!fvarTRemainingContactEmails}, where {!fvarTRemainingContactEmails} equals to

`(RIGHT({!varTContactEmail},LEN({!varTContactEmail})-FIND(";",{!varTContactEmail})))`

8. Decision - Remaining values to be parsed --- Yes: return to step 6
                                           --- No: proceed to email action
9. Email action - 
   Body: Hello flow is ok
   Subject: Flow worked
   Email addresses (collection):{!CollectionVariableContactsEmail}

Unfortunately the flow results in **Error - The "Email_Action_1" element in your flow has validation errors**.

Up and to step 5 the emails are correctly passed to the {!varTContactEmail} since I can print them in the screen.

Any ideas on what causes the fault will be much appreciated and if anyone is located in Greece or plans to visit Athens Greece ----> Beers are on me.

With regards
Dimitrios[image: Flow schema]